# Will Apple reject an Update that doesn't provide @2x graphics for the new iPad?

Tags: ipad, new-operator, retina-display

With 5.1 SDK and new iPad out, will Apple reject updates or new apps if they don't provide @2x graphics for the new iPad?

Is there a minimum like providing a least iPad @2x icons and splash screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they're going to reject your app (at least they didn't for non-retina-optimized iPhone apps when the iPhone 4 came out), but non-optimized images look somewhat ugly on the new iPad, so I strongly suggest you create 2x assets as quickly as possibly. Especially creating an optimized icon should be very simple, as you should already have created a 512x512px icon for the iTunes store.